# 画像リンクを作り、リンク先に飛んだら、ドメインが２つに増えて404エラーが出てしまう

Tags: html

WindowsでVScodeでポートフォリオを作成している初心者エンジニアです。
画像リンクを作り、リンク先に飛んだら、URLのドメインが２つに増えて404エラーが出てしまいます。

例：
`https://example.com/example.com/apple`

aタグのhrefを改善したり、検索してみたりしたのですが、検索の仕方が悪いのか出てこず此方で力を借りようと思った所存です。
プログラミングの質問や此方のサイトを使うのも初めてで、足りない事が御座いましたらアドバイス頂けると助かります。

此方コードになります。よろしくお願い致します。

```html
    <!-- Four -->
        <section id="four" class="wrapper alt style1">
            <div class="inner">
                <h2 class="major">制作物</h2>
                <p>
                    <p class="sample">Apple clone site</p>
                    <p>模写コーディング</p>
                    <br>https:/example.com/APPLE/
                    <br>
                
                        <p class="sample"><img src="images/img21.png"  width="570" alt="" /></p>
                    <a href="/APPLE/"></a></p>
                <section class="features">
                    
            </div>
        </section>

</section>
```

＜追記＞

最終的に今のコードはこちらになります。
VScodeのLiveServerでサイトを表示して画像のリンクをクリックすれば、正常に表示されるのですが、FileZillaを通して、エックスサーバーでサイトを表示した際に画像をクリックした場合404エラーが出てしまいます。

```html
<!-- Four -->
    <section id="four" class="wrapper alt style1">
        <div class="inner">
            <h2 class="major">制作物</h2>
            
            <p>
                <p class="sample">Apple clone site</p>
                <p>模写コーディング</p>
                <br>https://example.com/APPLE
                <br>
                <a href="https://example.com/APPLE" class="image"><img src="images/img21.png" width="570" alt="" /></a>
```

Comment: コードが無いと何が原因か分からないですね。コード(HTML)を掲載しましょう。

Comment: 誰が、どういう権利で、何を根拠にクローズしているのですかね。回答がついているのに、それまで無駄になるのだけど。

Comment: @WebSurfer クローズに関しては、 [こちら](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions) をご覧ください。
疑問が残る場合は、[メタサイト](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/)で質問してください。
メタサイトに関しては、[「メタ」とは？どのように機能しますか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta)をご覧ください。

Comment: ちなみに質問がクローズされていても投票がプラスの回答がついている質問は自動削除されないためナレッジベースとしては残ります。

Comment: コードを質問に記載する際は、[再現可能な短いサンプルコードの書き方](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)を参考にして下さい。
現在のコードですと、問題は再現しないと思いますし、それ以外の点も色々とおかしくなるはずです。
まずは、ブラウザで確認してみて下さい。

Comment: 質問者さんは実際に、 `example.com` というドメイン名を動作確認のために使用しているのでしょうか？また、動作確認用のドメイン・サーバーをどのように用意したのかについても教えていただけませんか？（そのために使用したソフトウェアや設定など）

Comment: 実際は別のドメイン名となっております。確認用はVScodeを（こちらは正常に表示されます。）サーバー側で表示した際はFileZillaを通してエックスサーバーを使用しております。

Answer (score 1):

> 画像リンクを作り、リンク先に飛んだら、URLのドメインが２つに増えて404エラーが出てしまいます。

想像ですが、a 要素の href 属性にリンク先を設定していて、パスが間違っているのでは？ 以下のようなルート相対パスを使ってませんか？

`href="/example.com/apple"`

試しに、以下のようにするとか、

`href="/apple"`

絶対パス、

`href="https://example.com/apple"`

を使ったらどうなりますか？ 少なくとも絶対パスならそれが正しければ期待通りになるはずなので試してみてください。(注: 絶対パスを使うことを推奨しているわけではありません。ルート相対パスを正しく使うのが良いと思います)

パスが理解できてなければ「絶対パス 相対パス ルート相対パス」などをキーワードにしてググると参考になる記事がヒットしますので調べてください。

Comment: <!-- Four -->
       <section id="four" class="wrapper alt style1">
        <div class="inner">
         <h2 class="major">制作物</h2>
         <p>
          <p class="sample">Apple clone site</p>
          <p>模写コーディング</p>
          <br>https:/exmple.com/APPLE/
          <br>
         
           <p class="sample"><img src="images/img21.png"  width="570" alt="" /></p>
            <a href="/APPLE/"></a></p>
         <section class="features">
          
        </div>
       </section>

     </section>  コードはこのようなものになります。此方絶対パスを使えていますか？全てのコードは膨大な為載せられないので必要なものがあれば教えて頂けると載せます。

Comment: > 此方絶対パスを使えていますか？ <=パスが理解できてなければ「絶対パス 相対パス ルート相対パス」などをキーワードにしてググると参考になる記事がヒットしますので調べてください。話はそれからにしましょう。でないと、話が通じないので。

Comment: それから、href="/APPLE/" の最後のスラッシュ / が何を意味するかも調べてください。トレイリングスラッシュでググると出てくるはず。

Comment: さらにもう一つ、あなたの言う「画像リンク」って何なのですか？　追記されたコード <p class="sample"><img src="images/img21.png"  width="570" alt="" /></p><a href="/APPLE/"></a></p> のことなら画像 img21.png はリンクになってません。はっきり言わせていただけると訳も分からず適当にコードを書いて投げられているとしか思えません。質問に書かれた情報が正しのかが疑わしいレベルです。

Comment: ご丁寧にありがとうございます。コメントを読み違えておりました申し訳ないです。パスの事もトレイリングスラッシュの事再学習させて頂きました。<a href="/APPLE" class="image"><img src="images/img21.png" width="570" alt="" /></a>を<a href="https://example.com/APPLE" class="image"><img src="images/img21.png" width="570" alt="" /></a>と過去に絶対パスにしていたのですが、VScodeのLiveServerでは画像をハイパーリンク状態にでき、しっかり指定したリンクサイトへ飛ぶことができていました。しかし、エックスサーバーでサイトを表示し画像をクリックした際に404になってしまいます。解決できないかとコードを書き換えていたのでグチャグチャで申し訳ありません。此方も画像リンクになっていませんか？個人で勉強している為情けないことに、ご指摘されないと気づけない部分もありご指摘いただけると助かります。私自身、文章力が無いのでうまく伝えられない部分も多いと思いますが、お付き合いいただけると幸いです。

Comment: まだ勉強不足です。https://example.com/APPLE は絶対パスではありません。日本語も変だし話が通じてません。

Comment: a href="　　https　　://example/APPLE" です。 https　://　はコメントで入力しても消えるようです。

Comment: 最終的にどういうコードを書いたのか、それでどうなるのかを質問欄に追記してください。追記ですよ。元の文に手を加えないで追記です。

Comment: 追記してみたのですが、いかがでしょうか。

Comment: > FileZillaを通して、エックスサーバーでサイトを表示した際に画像をクリックした場合404エラーが出てしまいます。⇒ エックスサーバーでは href に指定される URL にリソースがない（＝多分指定した URL が間違っている）からです。404 エラーというのは、ブラウザから Web サーバーに要求が出て、web サーバーに要求は届いたが（ということは href に指定した URL のドメインは合っている）、web サーバーが href に指定された URL のパスに従ってサーバー内でリソースを探した結果、見つからなかったということです。

Comment: ブラウザのアドレスバーに直接目的の apple ページの URL を打ち込んで エックスサーバーに要求をかけるとどうなりますか？　URL が正しければ表示されますよね？　それで正しく表示されるのなら、アドレスバーに打ち込んだ URL を問題の a タグの href に設定すれば、a タグクリック表示されるはず。正しい（はずの）URL をブラウザのアドレスバーに打ち込んでも 404 エラーが返ってくれば、それは問題外なのでまず先にそこを直しましょう。

Comment: AppleのページのURLを直接打ち込めば正しくエックスサーバー側でも表示されます。　https　://exmaple.com/APPLE　で正しく表示されるのですが、私のサイトから画像クリックし飛んだところexmple.comの部分が２つ表示されhttps　://example.com/example.com/APPLEとなり404が出ます。この404のページのURLのexample.comを1つ消せば404ではなくなり正しく表示されます。

Comment: 正しい絶対パスに代えたのであれば「画像クリックし飛んだところexmple.comの部分が２つ表示され」などということはあり得ません。一番最初の質問から私が想像した状態 href="/example.com/apple" から変わってないのでは？　ホントに間違いなく絶対パスに代えたのかよく確認してください。正しい絶対パスに代えたのに前の状態と同じになるということであれば、ブラウザのキャッシュから前の html が取得されてないか確認してください。